# PyGame - cannot provide text on screen using blit() call

Tags: python, pygame

I am implementing a simple version of Hangman as a total beginner.

In my code all text messages created inside the for-loop (`for event in pygame.event.get():`) are not shown on the screen. One can see, though, that they blink for a fraction of a second, where they should be, but they never fully show up.

```
bif = "bg.jpg"

import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen_widht = 600
screen_height = 300
user_guess = ''
word = "fuzzy"
guesses = 3
hidden_word = '-'*(len(word))
list_of_indexes = []
valid_letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',     'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_widht, screen_height), 0, 32)
background = pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 20)
text_color = (10, 10, 10)


def find_indexes(s, ch):
    global list_of_indexes
    list_of_indexes = [i for i, ltr in enumerate(s) if ltr == ch]



while True:

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    y = 10
    msg1 = font.render("Welcome to Hangman!", 1, text_color)
    screen.blit(msg1, (10, y))
    y += 20
    msg2 = font.render("The word now looks like this: " + hidden_word, 1, text_color)
    screen.blit(msg2, (10, y))
    y += 20
    msg3 = font.render("You have " + str(guesses) + " guesses left", 1, text_color)
    screen.blit(msg3, (10, y))
    y += 20 
    if guesses > 0 and '-' in hidden_word:
        msg4 = font.render("Input your guess", 1, text_color)
        screen.blit(msg4, (10, y))


    for event in pygame.event.get(): #there is the loop which does not blit messages on the screen
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            key = event.key
            user_guess = chr(key)     
            if user_guess not in valid_letters: 
                msg5 = font.render("Input valid guess", 1, text_color)
                screen.blit(msg5, (10, 90))
            else:
                msg7 = font.render("Your guess is " + user_guess, 1, text_color)
                screen.blit(msg7, (10, 90))
        if event.type == KEYUP and user_guess not in word and guesses > 0:
            guesses -= 1
        if user_guess not in word:
            msg8 = font.render("There are no " + user_guess + "`s in this word", 1, text_color)
            screen.blit(msg8, (10, 110))       
        else:
            msg6 = font.render("Your guess is correct", 1, text_color)
            screen.blit(msg6, (10, 110))
            find_indexes(word, user_guess)
            while len(list_of_indexes) > 0:
                for ind in list_of_indexes:
                    hidden_word = hidden_word[:ind] + user_guess + hidden_word[ind+1:]
                    list_of_indexes.remove(ind)


    if guesses == 0 and '-' in hidden_word:
        msg9 = font.render("You are completely hung", 1, text_color)
        screen.blit(msg9, (10, 130))

    if not '-' in hidden_word:
        msg10 = font.render("You guessed the word", 1, text_color)
        screen.blit(msg10, (10, 130))



    pygame.display.update()

time.sleep(0.03)
```

Comment: Just as a side note, it looks as though your sleep statement is outside of the while statement. I would also recommend changing the sleep command to the pygame clock module for your future games: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html

Answer (score 1):

The `if`-block

```
if user_guess not in word:
    msg8 = font.render("There are no " + user_guess + "`s in this word", 1, text_color)
    screen.blit(msg8, (10, 110))       
else:
    msg6 = font.render("Your guess is correct", 1, text_color)
    screen.blit(msg6, (10, 110))
    find_indexes(word, user_guess)
    while len(list_of_indexes) > 0:
        for ind in list_of_indexes:
            hidden_word = hidden_word[:ind] + user_guess + hidden_word[ind+1:]
            list_of_indexes.remove(ind)
```

is part of your event-handling loop (`for event in pygame.event.get():`), which is wrong.

It's indented one <kbd>TAB</kbd> to far. Otherwise, you draw the text *only* if there's an event in the event queue.

Comment: Thanks, gave me a good look in right direction. What I still don`t understand, is why those text lines were kind of blinking and disappearing...I guess it has something to do with screen been drawn several times a minute, but is there any more profound information about that anywhere?

Comment: What information are you looking for? You simply just draw the text only when there's an event in the event queue. Then, in the next iteration of your loop, the screen gets completely redrawn, and when there's no event, you simply don't draw the text.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you blit the message images inside the for loop. The events for loop is a loop that processes all the events in pygame like clicking on the screen or moving the cursor. Thus your messages are only being blitted to the screen when a pygame event occurs. You could fix this by creating variables with bullions inside of them. For instance:

```
A=False
if user_guess not in valid_letters: 
     A=True
```

Outside of the for loop lower down in your code you could write:

```
if A == True:
    msg5 = font.render("Input valid guess", 1, text_color)
    screen.blit(msg5, (10, 90))
```

This is one way of doing it. There is probably a more efficient way to do this, but you cannot blit something inside of the events loop if you want it to stay on the screen.